# Worklight - How to checkout from SVN and keep apps structure

Tags: eclipse, svn, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to add an existing worklight project to my SVN repository which went fine (removed the .project, .classpath files and the .settings folder). However I am having trouble with checking it out on a different PC. If I check it out using subclipse in Eclipse and as a new Worklight project it removes my apps folder and creates a new one thus removing my created files for Android\iPhone\mobile.
If I check it out normally it is not detected as a worklight project by the Worklight plugin.

Anyone that can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.project and .classpath needs to be checked in, they define the properties of your project. .settings folder is optional, however I'd recommend checking it in as well.
In general, this page outlines what you need to checkin and which files/folders should be ignored - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_integrating_with_source_contro.html&resultof%3D%2522%2573%2576%256e%2522%2520

Comment: Bit of a shame that the plugin does not allow you to import an existing Worklight project. I'm used to Java (web) apps with maven where I could just leave the .project and .classpath away and import them as existing maven projects.